# Connecting Adobe Reader with Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I am making an Excel sheet to help me to be able to easily track my ebooks and ebooks being read. so my Excel sheet contain the name of the book and the total number of pages, the current page I've reached and the % of my progress, status and the link of the ebook in the local hard drive.

What I want is that automatically when I hit the book's name(Hyper link) it will automatically to open the PDF file to the current page, for example if I am reading book X and I am on page 110, I want the link to open X.PDF on page 110, in HTML coding X.PDF#page=3 works 100%, but I want a way to hyper link and include the value inside some Excel's cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:
First we use the Shell command
with this syntax

```
Shell Acrobat_Path & " /A page=" & Current_Page & " " & SrcFile, vbNormalFocus
```

and Current_Page and SrcFile are the Excel's cells values

and assign this to a button with event click
eg

```
Sub Button1_Click()
...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like something for VBA. Ozgrid has dealt with this question before. 
Here:
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=29376
And here:
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=65950&page=1

The code they came up with is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "test.pdf#page=" & Target.Row
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it will not open to a specific page. It appears that Adobe Reader will only take this syntax for specific pages when it is handled through a web browser. VBA should have functionality to send this command to the web browser.